# Displaying current year in tumblr theme

Tags: php, tumblr

I want to place a copyright statement in the footer of my Tumblr theme something like "Acme Co © 2013" but i dont want to have to go in a update the year each year.

Normally with php this could be done using `date()` which would be fine, but although Tumblr is built on php i dont think end users can use it on the site, although there is a shorthand scripting language which i guess is compiled into php.

Any idea how i could do this ? I was thinking possibly with js but search bots don't have js so what would they see ?

Comment: I think search bots don't care about the year in your copyright.

Comment: Both the short and long answers to this question are: No. You have to do it manually.

Comment: How was this question closed as "not a real question"?! It is clear, concise, and straight to the point. It's not because you don't know the answer that the question becomes wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a theme variable, that will display the span of years a tumblelog has existed - `{CopyrightYears}`

Returns: `20XX-2013`

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script> document.write(new Date().getFullYear()) </script>
```

there you go... :-)