# Displaying the copyright years in Blogger template

Tags: themes, blogger, copyright-display

Is there a way to display the copyright years (including the first year) of a blog in a Blogger template?

Actually I can display only the last year (on user level, because is just a JavaScript code):

```
<span itemprop="copyrightYear"><script type='text/javascript'>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script></span>
```

I'm trying to find something like Tumblr does with the `{CopyrightYears}` do in Tumblr themes ([here's the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596300/displaying-current-year-in-tumblr-theme), but for Tumblr).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 1st year manually then getFullYear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can either edit the template HTML code OR better yet, go to **Layout** tab -> **Add a Gadget** (*at the bottom of the Footer section if possible*) -> on the popup window, select **HTML/Javascript** and copy/paste the following code:

**NOTE:** the **2015** year is an example, edit to the desired starting year.

```html
<span itemprop="copyrightYear">© 2015-<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script></span>
```

If you really want to add it to the template HTML code, go to the **Template** tab, click the down arrow next to **Costumise** and select **Edit HTML**.
Scroll down to the end tag `</body>` and copy/paste the above code just before that tag.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. In fact, I had already been using that way, of entering the first year manually, but I would like to know if Blogger will have a variable associated with the initial year of the blog, just as Tumblr does. This is ideal when editing the templates of various blogs.

Comment: I don't know about any Blogger variable that could work in that way... But not saying that don't exist as I know some new improvements were added in recent times...